# has the Python BigQuery API changed?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I was running an example in Spyder that worked previously:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import codecs

bigquery_client = bigquery.Client('myprojectID')

query_results = bigquery_client.run_sync_query("""
SELECT
    [ my query here ]  
FROM `[...]`;""")
```

Now I am getting an error

```
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'run_sync_query'
```

Has something changed?  Recently I reinstalled Anaconda Spyder and reinstalled google cloud sdk and python client api.

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/python-client-migration

Comment: That works.  If you answer it I will check-mark it

Answer (score 3):

See [this](http://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/python-client-migration)

All I did was Google (other search engines are available) "bigquery run_sync_query" and found that. My knowledge of BigQuery is very old, so I can't really claim to have worked on it!